# Broken libsdl2-2.0-0 packages prevents software/kernal updates

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, dpkg, update-manager

Today, I opted to download frequent software updates for Xubuntu to try avoiding broken system packages and other potentially system breaking faults. Yet ironically, I have experienced a common problem everyone usually has due to broken packages:

```
libsdl2-2.0-0 : Breaks: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.0.10+5) but 2.0.10+dfsg1-3 is to be installed
libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libsdl2-2.0-0 (!= 2.0.10+dfsg1-3) but 2.0.10+5 is to be installed
libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.10+dfsg1-3) but 2.0.10+5 is to be installed
```

I tried fixing it using It's FOSS and other Ask-Ubuntu articles, using the commands: `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install libsdl2-dev` once again with the same error as above. To fix the package, I'm getting an error about the package I'm trying to fix. Some articles say to remove malicious or just buggy packages but I yet to know anything like that on my computer. So I conclude, that I would like more suggestions from the growing Linux communities themselves! I'm new, and hope this was not a mouthful.

Operating system details: Xubuntu Ver:20.04

Comment: The and64 and i386 architectures of the same package have *different* version dependencies. A classic symptom of either a poorly-chosen non-Ubuntu source or a poorly chosen additional architecture.

Comment: I fixed part of the problem in recovery mode, which lets me proceed the update. It now has it's dependencies... but the package is incomplete. Maybe it won't be a problem.

Comment: Until you fix either the source problem or the architecture problem, your woes seem likely to re-occur.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for making my question clearer. Think people wouldn't have known the problem and just give it a glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news everyone! I was stuck on the solutions on the internet, until I completed the package. `sudo apt remove libsdl2-dev:amd64` Don't worry, I immediately reinstalled it using `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev:amd64`. I also realized I had some extra packages so I did `sudo apt autoremove`. So yeah, I hope I answered your problem idf you have a similar one. (Just in case, do `sudo apt-get if install`. To ensure you have dependencies.)